# Python and particle system

Tags: python

I have been using this code to add a new particle system and create a name for it... I need help to choose the particle type "HAIR" and set other parameters.. This script does not work because the [part.001] keeps changing and going up. It will only work once when creating the first name.
I will need one particle system, so I can apply the code on other objects as well. It is a bit confusing.
The MBall is used as a particle to cover the entire surface of an object.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.modifiers.new("part", type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')

bpy.data.particles["part"].type = 'HAIR'

bpy.data.particles["part"].count = 15000
bpy.data.particles["part"].use_advanced_hair = True
bpy.data.particles["part"].render_type = 'OBJECT'
bpy.data.particles["part"].instance_object = bpy.data.objects["Mball"]
bpy.data.particles["part"].particle_size = 0.15
bpy.data.particles["part"].emit_from = 'FACE'
bpy.data.particles["part"].distribution = 'RAND'
'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python console code.**

Add a particle system to the context object, *Note* the reference returned `ps` if the system names this system "part.001" it will be `ps.name`

```
>>> ob = C.object
>>> ps = ob.modifiers.new("part", 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
>>> ps.name
'part'
```

another

```
>>> ps = ob.modifiers.new("part", 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
>>> ps.name
'part.001'
```

The newly created particle system in the objects particle system collection

```
>>> psys = ob.particle_systems[ps.name]
```

`psys.settings` is a pointer to the particle settings stored in `bpy.data.particles` referred to by this particle system.  *Notice it has the name "part.001" but we haven't used the name to find it at all, only a reference and pointer*

```
>>> psys.settings
bpy.data.particles['part.001']
```

Use this pointer to set some properties (as in question code)

```
>>> psys.settings.count = 10000
>>> psys.settings.type = 'HAIR'
```

Can use this to set to a predefined set of settings, in this example a previously defined group of settings named "Wooble"

```
>>> psys.settings = D.particles['Wooble']
>>>
```