# How to create cell fracture in python

Tags: python, particles, add-on

Firstly, I am new to Blender. I am actually working on to create a hemispherical model with cell fractured property.

**1. I have done this work manually using cell Fracture add-on and now I want to automate using python.**

**2. I have written the code till particle implementation on the hemisphere. Now I want to create a cell fracture with those 100 particles.**

I have attached the hemisphere picture and the final output needed. I have also attached the code. Please provide me an insight on how to do this using python.

Code till Particles in Hemisphere:

```
import bpy


# Draw hemisphere of 1 m radius
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
    radius=1, 
    enter_editmode=True, 
    align='WORLD', 
    location=(0, 0, 0), 
    fill_type='TRIFAN',  # NOTHING  or NGON
    )
    
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(
    plane_co=(0, 0, 0), 
    plane_no=(0, -1, 0), 
    clear_inner=True,
    )
    
    
# Particles
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()

bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].count = 100

bpy.context.object.particle_systems["ParticleSettings"].seed = 1

bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].frame_end = 1
```

Image: Hemisphere with particle feature

[image: Hemisphere with Particles]

Image: Final output required with cell fracture

[image: Hemisphere with cell Fracture]

Thanks and Regards,

Sunag R A.

Comment: It is `\`` for the code block (under esc key), your are using `'` (beside enter key)

Comment: @HikariTW recommend tab formatting for code block (_ie_ all of code block  tabbed one extra right)   Wrapping in three backticks often leave a residual  when copy / pasting.

Comment: @batFINGER But I prefer using explicit bracket for code since there is no standard tabbed lens and in some editor, block tab just don't do the work. (And the residual should be considered as parser and html implement method?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Add particle system as suggested here [Python and particle system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140785/python-and-particle-system)

Make sure the cell fracture addon is enabled, and call the operator

```
bpy.ops.object.add_cell_fracture_objects()
```

Which uses defaults as mapped out in doc string

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects(
bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects(source={'PARTICLE_OWN'},
        source_limit=100,
        source_noise=0,
        cell_scale=(1, 1, 1),
        recursion=0,
        recursion_source_limit=8,
        recursion_clamp=250,
        recursion_chance=0.25,
        recursion_chance_select='SIZE_MIN',
        use_smooth_faces=False,
        use_sharp_edges=True,
        use_sharp_edges_apply=True,
        use_data_match=True,
        use_island_split=True,
        margin=0.001,
        material_index=0,
        use_interior_vgroup=False,
        mass_mode='VOLUME',
        mass=1,
        use_recenter=True,
        use_remove_original=True,
        collection_name="",
        use_debug_points=False,
        use_debug_redraw=True,
        use_debug_bool=False)
(undocumented operator)
```

Test code, produces result as in image above.

```
import bpy
from addon_utils import enable

# make sure cell fracture is enabled
enable("object_fracture_cell")

context = bpy.context

# Draw hemisphere of 1 m radius
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
    radius=1, 
    enter_editmode=True, 
    align='WORLD', 
    location=(0, 0, 0), 
    fill_type='NGON',  # NOTHING  or NGON
    )
    
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(
    plane_co=(0, 0, 0), 
    plane_no=(0, -1, 0), 
    clear_inner=True,
    )

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()        
    
# Particles

ob = context.object
ps = ob.modifiers.new("Part", 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM').particle_system
ps.seed = 1
ps.settings.count = 100
ps.settings.frame_end = 1

# cell fracture

bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects()
```

Comment: Thank you so much..!! This gives me the clarity of coding in Blender and also the solution to my problem.

Comment: I was trying the code provided by the chosen answer on Blender 2.92 which was failing, the needed change is to use `add_fracture_cell_objects` instead of `add_cell_fracture_objects`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The cell fracture in the version of `2.92.0 RC`  I am using is still working as above.  What version of 2.92 did you notice change in?.

Comment: Any possibility of defining the size of each fracture area? this could be useful to create voronoi treemaps